# A word to describe a "I didn't want to be in your club anyway!" style strop

Tags: single-word-requests

It's hard to describe exactly what I mean here.

There's a certain childish attitude where when rejected from something a person will dishonestly go "Well I didn't want to do that anyway!".

Also commonly seen is in the midst of a discussion when one is proven wrong they will simply proclaim "Boring!" and pretend the discussion was never important to them.

I'm pretty sure there's a word for this sort of attitude, or at the least a small 2 or 3 word expression, but it is escaping me what this is. Throwing a strop is the closest that comes to mind for me but I feel that doesn't quite sum up the attitude entirely accurately, being a more general word that would equally apply to a child who gets upset because they aren't allowed any chocolate with no association of pretending they didn't want it anyway.

Comment: The examples are contradictory. Does the person pretend they were not interested, or just get annoyed?

Comment: Do you need a formal answer for [*sour grapes*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sour%20grapes)?

Comment: A fox-and-the-grapes attitude.

Comment: 'strop'? You can use that as a noun? You've got my toves all mixed up.

Comment: "STROP"  (British, informal) a bad mood, a temper.  I had to look it up.

Answer (score 10):

How about this?

> **sour grapes**  PHRASE
> Used to refer to an attitude in which someone adopts a negative attitude to something because they cannot have it themselves.
> *‘government officials dismissed many of the complaints as sour grapes’*
> [LEXICO](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/sour_grapes)

Comment: Worth mentioning that the phrase originates in one of [Aesop's fables](https://read.gov/aesop/005.html)?

Comment: And the negative pronouncement belies the unchanged fact that they still would want that goal.

Answer (score -1):

The word you are looking for could be "anyway." It can signal the end of a discussion or a different opinion.

Could be [huffy](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/huffy).

Comment: The question was looking for a word to describe the attitude of the person in a strop, I don't think that "anyway" works here.

Comment: True☺️☺️ Could be huffy?

Comment: Hello, I know it's a little late to chip in but what springs to mind is :Accismus.. What do you think?